# How to set a parent property from inherited class

Tags: php, inheritance

I have this two classes:

```
<?php

class Test 
{
    protected $x = 0;

    public function setX($x)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    public function getX()
    {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}


class TestEx extends Test
{
    //parent::$this->x = 7; it gives this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$x' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in test.php

    public function getX()
    {
        echo parent::$this->x;
    }

}



$call_textex = new TestEx();
$call_textex->getX();


?>
```

Now, I would to set $x property of base class from the inherited class. How to achieve that in PHP5?

Comment: is this not working ? echo $this->x;

Comment: @HeXa Just it doesn't cross my mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your assignment in the constructor, and just use `$this`:

```
class TestEx extends Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->x = 7;
    }

    public function getX()
    {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.org/bbrGXFWP